# requirejs config with arbitrary data

Tags: requirejs

In an Dojo 1.7 AMD web app you can define also arbitrary data in the config object (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/loader/amd.html).

> The configuration object can also be used to set arbitrary, application-specific configuration data. All properties of a configuration object are shallow copied to require.rawConfig

I looked to the requirejs config page (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config), but I did not find a similar feature here. But I did not look into the source code.

Is there a possibility to store arbitrary infos in the requirejs config and get access to it?
Thanks alot in advance
Wolfgang

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12993804/164439

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see it is not supported.
You need to insert 1 line in the require.js source code to get this feature.

Here is an example:

```
require.config({
  test: "one",
  paths: {
    'jquery': 'libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery',
...
```

Along with the normal values you store your arbitrary information.

Then, you have to open the requirejs source code with a text editor.
Approximately in line 380 - 390 (depends on your version), function "makeRequire":
This function calls another called "mixin":

```
 mixin(modRequire, {
            nameToUrl: makeContextModuleFunc(context.nameToUrl, relModuleMap),
            toUrl: makeContextModuleFunc(context.toUrl, relModuleMap),
            defined: makeContextModuleFunc(context.requireDefined, relModuleMap),
            specified: makeContextModuleFunc(context.requireSpecified, relModuleMap),
            isBrowser: req.isBrowser,
            rawConfig: config
        });
```

After "isBrowser" write "rawConfig: config".

Now, in your amd module:

```
define(['require'], function (require){
  alert (require.rawConfig.test);
  ...
```

Update:
This feature will be implimented in requirejs 1.1.
https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/182