# How to load bootstrapped models in Backbone.js while using AMD (require.js)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, js-amd

Backbone.js documentation suggest loading bootstrapped models this way:

```
<script>
var Accounts = new Backbone.Collection;
Accounts.reset(<%= @accounts.to_json %>);
var Projects = new Backbone.Collection;
Projects.reset(<%= @projects.to_json(:collaborators => true) %>);
</script>
```

But this is a pattern that can't be used in **AMD approach (using require.js)**

The only possible solution is to declare **global variable storing JSON data** and use this variable later in relevant initialize methods.

Is there a **better way** to do this (without globals)?

Comment: Realized this isn't an answer, moved to comment: I use require.js and bootstrap. I basically do what you don't want to do. First fetched page has global variables of JSON data that I bootstrap. I copy/use these values for populating my initial models and collections. I'm not sure it's a bad way to do it. If you're worried about polluting the global space, can't you delete the variables after you've initially copied over the results?

Comment: what is the "@" symbol doing? what do "@accounts" and "@projects" represent?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is how we bootstrap data in a way that it doesn't pollute the global namespace. Instead it uses require.js exclusively. It also helps you provide the initial app configuration based on variables within the template.

### Within your rendered page

```html
<script src="require.js"></script>
<script>
define('config', function() {
  return {
    bootstrappedAccounts: <%= @accounts.to_json %>,
    bootstrappedProjects: <%= @projects.to_json(:collaborators => true) %>
  };
});
</script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

### `globals.js`

This file checks for config and extends itself using any of the data returned

```js
define([
  'config',
  'underscore'
], function(config) {

  var globals = {
  };
  _.extend(globals, config);
  return globals;

});
```

### `config.js`

This file is needed if you want be able to load the app regardless of if you have defined `config` in the page.

```js
define(function() {
  // empty array for cases where `config` is not defined in-page
  return {};
});
```

### `app.js`

```js
require([
  'globals',
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(globals) {

  if (globals.bootstrappedAccounts) {
    var accounts = new Backbone.Collection(globals.bootstrappedAccounts);
  }
  if (globals.bootstrappedProjects) {
    var projects = new Backbone.Collection(globals.bootstrappedProjects);
  }

});
```

Comment: I noticed also that config.js is needed for require.js optimizer to work without errors. Please explain why you suggest to add another layer using globals.js.

Comment: I find that this can work but because the modules are loaded async, sometimes the dummy will load before the real options. I also found when optimising the dummy will be preferred to the real options. It's an interesting idea but in my experience this doesn't work well at all, and I think there are other better ways to achieve this in the other answers.

Comment: This is the setup that is working for me, what I do in order to make it work with the optimizer is to `excludeShallow` my config.js that way it will always use the module defined in the html

Comment: @dlrust please update your answer using Asgaroth recommendation

Comment: This works, but a word of caution. Ensure you don't have a '</script>' anywhere in your data, otherwise it'll get processed and mess up your tags in spectacular fashion.

Comment: anyone have a link that describes this @ notation/syntax? I assume it's a RequireJS thing?

Answer (score 31):

Looks like you can use the require.config() function or the "require" global with the "config" option in order to pass data to a module through the special dependency "module". See http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-moduleconfig:

> There is a common need to pass configuration info to a module. That
>   configuration info is usually known as part of the application, and
>   there needs to be a way to pass that down to a module. In RequireJS,
>   that is done with the config option for requirejs.config(). Modules
>   can then read that info by asking for the special dependency "module"
>   and calling module.config().

So, for bootstrapping models we have, in the top level HTML page:

```
<script>
var require = {
    config: {
        'app': {
            bootstrappedAccounts: <%= @accounts.to_json %>
            bootstrappedProjects: <%= @projects.to_json(:collaborators => true) %>
        }
    }
};
</script>
<script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Then in the app module (app.js), we have:

```
define(['module'], function (module) {
    var accounts = new Backbone.Collection( module.config().bootstrappedAccounts );
    var bootstrappedProjects = new Backbone.Collection( module.config().bootstrappedProjects );
});
```

Here "module" is a special dependency supplied for these types of cases.

This is untested but looks pretty sure from the documentation.

Comment: Nice solution, worked for me and should also work with the optimizer (havent come that far yet). I noticed that the `'app'` corresponds to the module where the objects are loaded, so if you want to use the bootstrapped data in another module (eg `otherModule.js`) it needs to be in the `config : { 'otherModule': otherModuleBootstrapData }`

Comment: I wish I found your solution earlier! Just spent three hours and made the same conclusion. Was about to post it as Q&A and found your reply. :-)

Comment: Great answer. Note that one does have to use `define()` (as shown in the answer) rather than `require()` in order for module.config() to work.

Answer (score 11):

In RequireJS this is done with the config option for `requirejs.config()`. Modules can then read that info by asking for the special dependency "module" and calling `module.config()`. Example:

**index.html**

```
<script>
  var require = {
    config: {
      'app': {
        'api_key': '0123456789-abc'
      }
    }
  };
</script>
<script src="js/libs/require.js" data-main="js/main"></script>
```

**main.js**

```
require( ['app'], function(App) {
  new App();
});
```

**app.js**

```
define( ['module'], function(module) {
  var App = function() {
    console.log( 'API Key:', module.config().api_key );
  };

  return App;
});
```

Just note that the name of the configuration-object **must match** the name of the module. In my example the name of the module was `app`, so the name of the configuration-object needed to be named `app` as well. In the module, you will need to include `['module']` as a dependency and call `module.config()[property name]` to retrieve the configuration-data.

Read the documentation about this: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-moduleconfig

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do a `define` within main.js? The main.js file seems a little unnecessary here, unless main needs to use `require` instead of `define`. To say it another way, could you copy all code from app.js into main.js, and then change the config to `config.main` instead of `config.app`? Then you could delete app.js all together. In testing, this seems to work, but as I'm new to requirejs, it might be bad practice.

Comment: As long it's a module, it's able to retrieve the data assigned to it in `module.config()[property/module name]`. However, typically `main.js` is reserved for requiring core modules within the application as dependencies by way of the `require` statement.

Comment: I may not have used the best module name in the example above. Instead of `app.js` pretend it's `apis/GoogleAnalytics.js` since the data it's retrieving is `api_key`. This would be it's own module that is required from `main.js`, not the entire application itself. In which case the configuration-object would look like:
`require = { config: { 'apis/GoogleAnalytics' : { 'api_key': '0123456789-abc' } } };`

Answer (score 6):

Some of the answers here got me close to my similar problem but nothing nailed it. In particular the top ranked and accepted answer gave seemed to give me a nasty race condition where sometimes the dummy object would load first. This also happened 100% of the time when used with the optimiser. It also uses explicit string names for the module which the require documentation specifically advises you not to do.

Here's how I worked it. Similar to Brave Dave, I use the config object to capture parameters (in my case from a jsp page) like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var require = {
        config: {
            options : { 
                bootstrappedModels : ${models}
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In particular note that my parameters are in an object called options. **This name is not optional!** Though the documentation makes no mention of this, the following is how require will load your config (line 564 in requirejs 2.1.1) :

```
config: function () {
    return (config.config && config.config[mod.map.id]) || {};
},
```

The key point is that there has to be property on the  config object with the key mod.map.id which resolves to 'options'.

From here you can now access the models like so

```
define(['module'], function(module){
    console.log(module.config().bootstrappedModels);
    //...
});
```

Comment: @BraveDave's answer works for me, but this one doesn't, although I wish it did.

Comment: @shioyama, interesting. What version of requirejs are you using? What actually happened when you tried this way? Seems there are some fairly major inconsistencies if we're all getting different results.

Comment: I haven't been able to get @BraveDave's solution, or this one to work. For now I'm using the sloppy global variable method. In my module, `module.config().myVar` is always null.

Comment: Good point about the race condition. I noticed the same problem. The solution that worked for me was to use @OllieEdwards way - excludeShallow: ["config"]

Answer (score 3):

You could add a loopy function at the end of your AMD module to check for when the init method is defined (so that it can be populated after body, or loaded from an include). that way the module is guaranteed available and initialization can happen when it's ready.

```
require(...,function (...) {
   //define models collections, etc..

   var initme = function () {
     if(document.initThisModule) 
       document.initThisModule();
     else
       setTimeout(initme, 10);
   }();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not (too) familiar with the AMD approach, but instead of using a global variable, why don't you add the JSON to the dom.

for example:

```
var json = ...,
$jsonContainer = $(json).wrap("<script id='json-container' type='text/javascript'>").appendTo($("body"));
```

Then, instead of an embedded script tag as suggested by the backbone documentation, inside the document ready:

```
$(function(){
    MyCollection.reset($("#json-container").html());
    ...
});
```

Comment: While this would work (as would a global, per the original question), it is contrary to the AMD philosophy.  An AMD module should declare all of its dependencies and ideally not rely on globals, which "document" certainly is (used by $ to look up the HTML).

Answer (score 2):

How about doing something like this:

```
<script>
define('Models', ['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
    var Models = {
        Accounts: new Backbone.Collection,
        Projects: new Backbone.Collection
    };

    Models.Accounts.reset(<%= @accounts.to_json %>);
    Models.Projects.reset(<%= @projects.to_json(:collaborators => true) %>);

    return Models;
});
</script>
```

Then you'll be able to use Models in other modules like this:

```
var models = require(['Models']);
models.Accounts.doWhatYouNeed();
```

or this:

```
define(['any', 'dependencies', 'and', 'Models'], function(a, b, c, Models) {
   // Models will be available here
});
```

Comment: @opengrid - that's why it's in a <script> tag

Comment: I like this as sort of an inversion of @dlrust's answer.  Although, it relies on your views and collections being able to handle any data that is 'reset' after they might already have been rendered, which while generally a good idea can involve a lot of extra bookkeeping.

Comment: Aren't the Collection instantiated everytime that `require(['Models']);` is called?

Answer (score 2):

Like described above, the 'data module' (or config, or whatever you want to call it) could be included in a file that is already generated anyway (e.g. index.html) but I think this is rather ugly.

Another way would be to declare it in its own module file but this would require an extra roundtrip to the server in production environments. As soon as you want to build and optimize your requirejs dependencies, the data module cannot be included because it is dynamically generated upon page load.

A third option might be to append it to one of the files that you serve (for example, the optimized requirejs file), but I have no idea of how/if that could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Ansewr by @dlrust work but it not able extend param and pass more than from one place in code. If you try do something like this in your render template:

```
<script>
    define('config', function() {
        return {
            bootstrappedAccounts: <%= @accounts.to_json %>,
            bootstrappedProjects: <%= @projects.to_json(:collaborators => true) %>
        };
    });
</script>
```

and in another file add some data

```
<script>
    define('config', function() {
        return {
            goods: <%= some data %>,
            showcaseList: <%= some json or array %>
        };
    });
</script>
```

it was overwrite (**NOT EXTEND!!!**). In config will be only last declared data.

My solution: used Backbone model with set/get data.

## `app.js`

```
define("App", [], function() {
    window.App = {
        // модели
        Model: {},
        // коллекции
        Collection: {},
        // виды
        View: {},
        // роутеры
        Router: {},
        // модальные окна
        Modal: {},
        // UI компоненты
        UI: {}
    };
    return window.App;
});
```

## `global.js`

```
define(["App", "underscore", "backbone"], function(App, _, Backbone) {
    "use strict";

    // модель глобальных данных
    App.Model.Global = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {}
    });

    return new App.Model.Global;    
});
```

## `index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--HEAD_START-->
        <script type="text/javascript" data-main="/app/init" src="/app/require/require.js"></script>
        <!--HEAD_END-->
    </head>

    <body>          
        <div id="tm-inner-wrap">
            <div id="loader"><i class="uk-icon-refresh uk-icon-spin"></i></div>
            <!--HEADER_START-->
            <?= $this->includeTpl('header_view'); ?>
            <!--HEADER_END-->

            <!--CONTENT_START-->
            <div>your html content data</div>
            <!--CONTENT_END-->

            <!--FOOTER_START-->
            <?= $this->includeTpl('footer_view');?>
            <!--FOOTER_END-->

            <script>
                require(["global"], function(Global) {
                    Global.set("notifyList", <?=json_encode($this->notifyList);?>);
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

another template

## `someTemplate.php`

```
<div class="tm-inner-body">
    <div class="uk-container uk-container-center">
        // content data
    </div>
</div>

<script>    
    require(["global", "module/index"], function(Global) {
        Global.set("goodList", <?=json_encode($this->goodList);?>);
    });
</script>
```

## `index.js`

```
require(["App", "core", "jquery", "uikit!uikit-addons-min", "underscore", "backbone", "global", "module/good/goodView"], function(App, Core, $, UIkit, _, Backbone, Global, goodView) {
    "use strict";

    // Global.get("notifyList"); its too able

    App.Collection.Good = new Backbone.Collection(Global.get("showcaseList")["items"]);

    // вид списка товаров
    App.View.GoodList = Backbone.View.extend({
        // елемент
        el: ".tm-good-list",
        // init
        initialize: function() {
            this.collection = App.Collection.Good;
            // список товаров
            this.drawList();
        },
        // отрисовка списка
        drawList: function() {
            this.$el.empty();
            this.collection.each(function(item, index) {
                this.$el.append(this.drawItem(item));
            }, this);
        },
        // отрисовка елемента
        drawItem: function(data) {
            var good = new goodView({model: data});
            return good.render().el;
        }
    });

    App.View.Index = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "body",
        // пользовательские события
        events: {
            //
        },
        // init
        initialize: function() {
            var $this = this;
            if(Global.get("showcaseList")) new App.View.GoodList();
        }
    });

    new App.View.Index();
});
```

### File structure:

[image: file structure]