# global variables in requireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to load bootstrapped models in Backbone.js while using AMD (require.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916073/how-to-load-bootstrapped-models-in-backbone-js-while-using-amd-require-js)

This is a simple demo about my problem.

I need to access the `id_user` in `main.js` file. My question is, how to avoid global variables in this situation? It is bad practice use global variables for this purpose?

**main.js**

```
require({
    paths : {
        jQuery : 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min'
    }
});

require([ 'jQuery' ], function() {
       alert(id_user);
    });
```

**index.php**

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function users() {
    id_user = <?php echo $id; ?>
}

users();
</script>
```

Comment: I'd say you don't get around a global var. But using more than one is bad practice :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There shouldn't be any global variable for such usage in project using requirejs as it is to handle modules and all modules (and their properties/methods) are never declared globally to keep the environment nice and clean. If you need one module to use a variable set in an other module then they should either talk to each other via some API or have that variable set as a property, require the module and get the property that way.

But maybe you should ask yourself if you actually need requirejs. If you want to build a proper module based application (which I am not sure you are if you wonder how to pass variable around) then yes, if all you want is to load few files from JS then LazyLoad (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) is probably the answer. Just saying it's worth thinking about depending on your case specially considering the footprint of requirejs.

Comment: A hacky way to pass variable around is to set them in the DOM in a <meta name="MyData" value="Boo" id="myData" /> and just grab the value attribute.

Comment: but in a simple case where is needed to pass a php variable to the main.js. What type of API are you talking about?

Comment: You should declared a module holding the value. as requirejs is loaded just above you should be able to do define('user', { id: <?php $id ?> }); and then from main.js require('user', function(user) { console.log(user.id) });

Comment: ok. I understand the idea. Just one more question please. The new module with `define('user', { id: <?php $id ?> });` should be an JS file correct? So, it is impossible access the php content (id) inside.

Comment: I don't know requirejs deeply but it won't take you long to type that in and find out. If not the real clean way to grab that data is via ajax. Or just use a global object to store whatever you need and query that. Cos let's be honest we all say don't use global variables but what does rerquirejs does and hell it doesn't even use a single object but multiple global functions :)

Comment: the footprint can be totally negated by the included compressor which dumps the JS into a single file and removes itself as a dependency

Comment: How come AMD-compliant scripts like jQuery still create a global `$` variable?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the ability to bootstrap config variables into your project. This answers your question

[How to load bootstrapped models in Backbone.js while using AMD (require.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916073/how-to-load-bootstrapped-models-in-backbone-js-while-using-amd-require-js/10288587#10288587)