# RequireJS--always load dependency with library

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

There's a Backbone plugin that I want to use across my entire codebase, but I don't want to have to require it alongside Backbone every time I want to use it. Right now, my scripts look like:

```
define(
  ['backbone','backbone.eventstreams'], 
  function(Backbone){
    //...
  }
);
```

`Backbone.EventStreams` simply extends `Backbone`, so it would be nice to have the functionality automatically available whenever I include Backbone without having to add it separately to each file.

Pyykkis, in his TodoMVC example, [simply requires it at the entry point](https://github.com/pyykkis/todomvc/blob/bacon-transparency-require/labs/dependency-examples/bacon_transparency_require/src/main.coffee) and that appears to make it available throughout. However, this feels like a hack to me.

Are there any drawbacks to this approach, and if so, what would be the right way to tackle this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505925/

Answer (score 0):

There shouldnt be any global variables in a project thats using requireJS , thats one of the motive behind using requireJS , that is to avoid polluting the Global namespace ...Just by loading any module at the entry point by using require doesnt make it global ..Check out this link , this might be helpful [global variables in requireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199622/global-variables-in-requirejs)

Comment: I understand that there should be no global variables in a RequireJS project. What I want is for `Backbone.EventStreams` to be loaded as part of `Backbone` "for free", whenever I require `Backbone`. Updated question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Configure requirejs in your entry point main.js file

```
require.config({
        paths: {
            backbone: libs / backbone,
            underscore: libs / underscore,
            jquery: libs / jquery
        },
        shim: {
            'backbone': {
                //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading
                //backbone.js
                deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
                //Once loaded, use the global 'Backbone' as the
                //module value.
                exports: 'Backbone.EventStreams'
            }
        });
```

Here whenever you define or require backbone you can directly access methods on Backbone.EventStreams objects

Answer (score 0):

So based on what you're saying, this plugin has a dependency on Backbone.
Backbone don't support AMD, so you need to use shim command to load it.

To simple load Backbone you'll need something like this.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        backbone: libs / backbone,
        underscore: libs / underscore,
        jquery: libs / jquery
    },
    shim: {
        'backbone': {                
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    });
```

Now to use the Backbone.EventStreams plugin as you said, this plugin has a dependecy on Backbone, so you need have something like this.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        backbone: libs / backbone,
        underscore: libs / underscore,
        jquery: libs / jquery
        backboneEventStreams: libs / BackboneEventStreams (path to js file)
    },
    shim: {
        'backbone': {                
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'BackboneEventStreams' :{
             deps:['Backbone'], 
             exports: 'BackboneEventStreams'
        }
    });
```

Use Exports to specify the name that you want to use for that module in your app.

Hope it helps