# Use require.js to run common code before module is required

Tags: javascript, requirejs, momentjs

I'm using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) on a few different pages in an international site. Each page uses require.js to require in Moment.

Moment allows you to [set the locale](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) to display dates in that locales format. However, this code has to be run on every page Moment is loaded (since I'm never sure which page the user loads first).

```
var Moment = require('moment');
// configure locale
```

What I want to do is move the code to configure the locale to something like a pre-require step so that I don't have to remember to configure the locale on every page (and it becomes more DRY). So all I would have to do is

```
var Moment = require('moment');
```

and the pre-require step would already have configured the locale.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, like this:

1. Create a module that will be called `moment-configured`:

   ```
   define(['moment'], function (moment) {
       // Call what you need to call to configure moment...
       return moment;
   });
   ```
2. Use a `map` configuration so that everybody who loads moment really loads your `moment-configured` module whereas `moment-configured` loads the real `moment`:

   ```
   map: {
       '*': {
           moment: 'moment-configured'
       },
       'moment-configured': {
            moment: 'moment'
       }
   }
   ```

This method is adapted from the example in [RequireJS' documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#noconflictmap) about how to have jQuery be automatically loaded with `noConflict`. With this map configuration, all modules that require `moment` will get `moment-configured`, except for `moment-configured` which will get the real `moment`.

Answer (score -1):

The require config object can be given a callback to be executed after dependencies are loaded and before require() is defined:

```
requirejs.config({
    deps: ['moment'],
    callback: function (moment) {
        console.log(moment().format());
    }
});
```