# Perf is not defined - running react app with webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to measure react performance with [Perf addon](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html), but when I'm trying to run Perf.start() in my console i get an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Perf is not defined(…)`

Worth mentioning, that I've installed the plugin through npm and have a `require('react-addons-perf')` sitting in my main.js file.

I have a guess that this problem related to the fact that i'm running a webpack-dev-server and the global variable is not properly exposed, but unfortunately hav no idea, how to properly approach it. Can anyone help me with that?

Here's my [webpack.config](http://codepen.io/glebez/pen/bELEeq?editors=0010) file contents on codepen for the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there might be changes within your webpack.config that could change the scoping or expose a var to be accessible via the global scope, but one quick way would be to simply use

```
global.Perf = require('react-addons-perf');
```

This should grant you access via console.

But one must say that it is maybe not intended to expose vars globally [global variables in requireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199622/global-variables-in-requirejs)

And maybe try to find a way to trigger the Perf.start() and Perf.stop() from within your code, not the console!

Comment: Great, thanks, it worked and seems less work, than the solution, that i came up with, so marking it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution, that worked for me:

1. Install the [npm expose-loader module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expose-loader)
2. Add the following line to your webpack config loaders:

   ```
   { test: require.resolve("react-addons-perf"), loader: "expose?Perf" }
   ```

This expose-loader module is a great way to expose module exports to global scope.

Comment: Alternate syntax: within you JS code, do `require('expose?Perf!react-addons-perf');`