# RequireJS - pass parameters into module for initialization

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, amd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to load bootstrapped models in Backbone.js while using AMD (require.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916073/how-to-load-bootstrapped-models-in-backbone-js-while-using-amd-require-js)

I am currently creating a RESTful API for one of our projects and also wanted to provide a Javascript library to access it.

Since I like the AMD principle and using require.js, I would provide an AMD module as well.
The problem is: the initialization of the module would require some information like the API key on initialization.

How do I pass such parameters into a module upon initalization?

Answer (score 14):

If you have something like:

```
define(['dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3'], function (dep1, dep2, dep3) {

    var module = {
        ...
    };

    return module;

});
```

change it to:

```
define(['dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3'], function (dep1, dep2, dep3) {
    var module = {
        ...
    };

    var init = function (options) {
        // Initialize here
        return module;

    };

    return init;
});
```

Then after requiring your module somewhere, you can *call* it to initialize. You might also want to look into the factory pattern if you need something more complex and return the factory.

require.js does not restrict you in what you return. It can be a simple object, a string, a function...

Comment: Well, that won't work. I am requiring the API module on different spots of my application and can't put the initalization parameters into every module that wants to use the API. It has to be initialized before anyone makes use of the exported module object.

Answer (score 6):

I think what your looking for is the ability to set config variables that get picked up by the module. Here is an example using require.js

[How to load bootstrapped models in Backbone.js while using AMD (require.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916073/how-to-load-bootstrapped-models-in-backbone-js-while-using-amd-require-js/10288587#10288587)

Comment: That pattern is interesting. But if I'm going to create my official AMD module for the API this way, every developer has to follow that pattern - If he likes it or not. But I think its the only way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

One other possibility that came to my mind is to use a serverside script to manipulate the source of the module when you are requesting it.

For example when you have to pass an API-key into the module, you do the following:

Before you do your first define() call, put the following code:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        api: 'https://api.example.com/api.amd.js?api_key=f615ac61&'
    }
});
```

This enables you to simply require your API from anywhere like this:

```
require(['api'], function(api){

});
```

So the server recieves the request - maps it thorugh mod_rewrite to some script, takes the GET parameter and puts it on the correct place in the module sourcecode, then returns the custom source.

Thats the way I solved this by now and it works like a charm, without the need to change any behaviour of the developers and it makes use of functionality thats already built into requirejs.

Comment: Notice the & character at the end of the URL. require.js has some issues with GET parameters and will add an additional ".js" at the end of the requested url. Adding the final & character makes sure your api key is parsed correctly on serverside.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with require.js, but you can with [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js) or some other module library. In Frame you would do that like this:

```
//moduleName.js

(function(exports){
    exports.moduleName = function(args){
        // do stuff
    }
})(window.exports);


// in main js file

var exports = {}; // global variable

Frame('moduleName.js');
Frame(function(next){
    var myArgs = { ... settings ... };
    exports.moduleName(myArgs);
    next();
});
Frame.init();
```

Comment: Well thank you - but I won't switch the module loader in the current state of my project...

Comment: looking a little more at require, you could do the same thing with it.

Comment: make a module that loads your original module into a function in a global object, then call that function with the params you wanted to pass to the original module.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use a namespaced variable, and then to reference the appropriate object when you initialize the specific library?  Maybe I don't understand exactly what you want  require.js to do, but it looks like you call it from your main.js in any event, so I'm pretty sure it would work...  I don't think you can do it like  `<script = "require.js?apiKey=jsdfhjkfklsjkfdjks">`

```
var libData = {
   apiKey: "jsdfhjkfklsjkfdjks",
   otherpram: "userIDorsomething"
}

require(libData.apiKey);
```

but if you needed to send the apikey in the url parameter of the page, you could use a script like this to get the parameters:

```
<script>
      function getQueryParams(qs) {
            qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");
            var params = {},
                tokens,
                re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

            while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
                params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
                    = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
            }

            return params;
        }

// assuming the page is loaded like page.html?apikey=jsdfhjkfklsjkfdjks

     apiKey = getQueryParams(document.location.search).apiKey;
```

// however you have to call require, pass the api key?

```
</script>
```