# RequireJS include script with paramaters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I've been playing with BackboneJS, MarionetteJS and RequireJS recently and was wondering how to include an external script with paramaters and settings?

Normally it would be included like so:

```
<script src="http://domain.com/api.js?apikey=API_KEY">
    {
        settingOne: "settingOneValue",
        settingTwo: "settingTwoValue"
    }
</script>
```

Is it possible to do something similar with RequireJS?  The script is needed reasonably globally for a project so could be added "normally" if needs be.

*Additional/optional requirement:* Preferably the `APIKEY` will be stored in an external file with other project settings.

Comment: If you support jsonp like-envirement you could require the script like so: `require(['http://domain.com/api.js?apikey=API_KEY&callback=define',...], ...)`

Comment: I guess this answer might be of interest : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10329014/1236044

Answer (score 1):

You may use **[urlArgs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs)**: extra query string arguments appended to URLs that RequireJS uses to fetch resources.

Or other option would be to write custom [**loader plugin**](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html), that would have logic that you need.