# Setting a global REST root url in a Backbone.js application

Tags: backbone.js

In backbone.js, you have to set the rooturl of every model manually. Is there a way we can set this in a single location once and all models will use it?

For eg. `api.site.com` will be the REST service, but for testing purpose, it may be at `localhost:1000` I need to be able to change the root url of the service easily and not have them all over the place in the many models that exist in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you mean setting `urlRoot` for every model manually.
Presumably you do

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  urlRoot: '/mymodel',
  ...

});
```

right? Then each model instance naturally has the same `urlRoot`.Any other model instance of say `MyOtherModel` would have some different `urlRoot`.

If for some reason you need to be using the same `urlRoot`, I would guess it would be because the models share attributes. This should hint to inheritance or extension so you could do:

```
var BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/mymodel'
});

var MyModel = BaseModel.extend({
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 13):

I've been playing around with the most elegant way to do this when using Backbone with AMD (require.js). This is what I've come up with, and like best [so far].

First, bootstrap the data in, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916073/how-to-load-bootstrapped-models-in-backbone-js-while-using-amd-require-js/10288587#10288587).

**index.htm (application entry point)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script>
    var require = {
      config: {
        // key name is module, value is data to give module
        'models/Base': {
          apiUrl: '/some/path/to/api',
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
<script data-main="js/main" src="vendor/require/require-jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Next, define a base class for Backbone models, like this:

**js/models/Base.js (notice this module name matches the module name in config above)**

```
define(['module', 'backbone'],
  function(module, Backbone){

    return Backbone.Model.extend({
      getApiUrl: function(){
        return module.config().apiUrl;
      }
    });

  }
);
```

Finally, extend all of your Backbone models from that base, like this:

**js/models/User.js**

```
define(['models/Base'],
  function(BaseModel){

    return BaseModel.extend({
      urlRoot: function(){
        return this.getApiUrl() + '/user';
      }
      // ... more cool stuff here
    });

  }
);
```

This is tangentially related to an [earlier question I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882836/best-practice-for-shared-objects-in-backbone-require-application) regarding Backbone and Require.JS.

Related reading: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-moduleconfig

Answer (score 8):

What I understand is :

You have several models: model1 and model2

The root URL can be either `http://api.site.com` or `http://localhost:8080` depending on whether you are working locally or externally. And someday it could be `http://api.anothersite.com`

I would do somthing like this then :

```
// Global var before any other JS code, you comment line depending on which one applies
var ROOT = 'http://api.site.com'
// var ROOT = 'http://localhost:8080'

var Model1 = Backbone.Model.extend({
urlRoot: ROOT+'/model1',
...
});

var Model2 = Backbone.Model.extend({
urlRoot: ROOT+'/model2',
...
});
```

But be careful with this, you may forget to switch from one url to the other one when commiting. Better is to handle relative paths if they'd apply.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best way to achieve this is by overriding the `Backbone.sync` method, and prepend your root url there. This because it's not the responsibility of the model to know the API domain.

```
// Cache Backbone.sync for later use
var sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options){
  options.beforeSend = function(){
    this.url = API_ROOT_URL + this.url;
  };
  return sync.call(this, method, model, options);
};
```

And then you can create your models as you would normally do:

```
var Resource = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/resources',
});
```

I use this same method to append an `.json` extension to all URL's to prevent JSON flashes through browser cache.

Comment: I don't think this works.  `beforeSend()` is called after the request has already been opened with the original url.

Comment: It's exactly the use of `beforeSend`; *beforeSend Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, PlainObject settings ) A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent. Use this to set custom headers, etc. The jqXHR and settings objects are passed as arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the request. As of jQuery 1.5, the beforeSend option will be called regardless of the type of request.*

Comment: It is before the request is sent but after it is initialized (with the existing url).  My answer works correctly.

Comment: I was using it and I think it seemed to work initially but I later ran into issues.  I'm using Backbone.NativeAjax and node-xmlhttprequest to use backbone models on the server and node-xmlhttprequest parsed the url components from the initial options and did not update the parsed components after calling beforeSend().

I suggest my answer instead since it doesn't depend on implementation details of the ajax call.

Comment: So the problem is not with my solution. Only in combination with a non-standard Backbone setup. Anyway, your answer is a good alternative when people don't use jQuery as backend. You might want to add that exception to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from https://coderwall.com/p/8ldaqw/add-a-root-url-to-all-backbone-api-request

```
var backboneSync = Backbone.sync;

Backbone.sync = function (method, model, options) {
    /*
     * Change the `url` property of options to begin
     * with the URL from settings
     * This works because the options object gets sent as
     * the jQuery ajax options, which includes the `url` property
     */
    options = _.extend(options, {
        url: API_ROOT + _.result(model, 'url')
    });

    /*
     *  Call the stored original Backbone.sync
     * method with the new url property
     */
    backboneSync(method, model, options);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just start your url from **'/'**.
Thus you'll be not depend on either localhost or real domain.

Answer (score 0):

This is really old post, but I think that my version can be useful for someone. I use backbone with require.js and my server-side and client-side completely separated. I give to know for the client app where is API root at the same time, when I declare requirejs script:

```
<script 
     data-main="js/main" 
     data-api-url="https://api/v1/" 
     src="js/require.js">
</script>
```

and then i get in my backbone module:

```
var $scriptEl = $('script[data-main]'),
      base = $scriptEl.attr('data-api-url');

var BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: base
});

var model = BaseModel.extend({});
```

This is the most elegant way which I could find..