# Parameters to main with requireJS and data-main

Tags: requirejs

I am wondering if there is a way to pass parameters to the requireJS with the data-main parameter.

```
<script data-main="Main"  src="lib/require/require.js"></script>
```

I can introduce globals:

```
<script>
    var mainId = "Main";
    var mainTarget = "body";
</script>
<script data-main="Main"  src="lib/require/require.js"></script>
```

But I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it. Thanks!

EDIT:

Simon, this is a great plan I think for the mainTarget value.

```
require([
    'plugins/load!./'+mainId+'.htm',
    'plugins/load!./'+mainId+'.css'
],function(html,css){
    var Main = function(){
        this.__proto__ = mainTarget;
    }
    new Main();
}
```

How do I apply this to mainId?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load bootstrapped models in Backbone.js while using AMD (require.js)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916073/how-to-load-bootstrapped-models-in-backbone-js-while-using-amd-require-js)

Answer (score 15):

One way to achieve this is to create a global or common module and just use it as a dependency:

**global.js**

```
define({
    foo: 'test',
    bar: 'red'
});
```

Using the global:

```
require(['global'], function(global) {
    console.log(global.foo) // 'test'
});
```

This relies on the global object properties being held within a JS file. 
It's also a common pattern to output data from the server side into a JS object in the HTML page. To do this you simply give your module a name.

```
<head>
    <script>
        define('global', {
            mainId: 'Main',
            mainTarget: 'body' 
        })
    </script>
</head>
```

**main.js**

```
require(['global'], function(global) {
    console.log(global.mainId) // 'Main'
});
```

If you define a module that needs a global property, just set the `global` module as a dependency.

You can also use the `priority` configuration option to ensure your global module is loaded before anything else - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config