# Global Resource Sharing on large Backbone / RequireJS App

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am building my first large Backbone + Requiere APP and i came across a scenarios where it would just make sense to access some kind of an "app wide" scope. I was thinking of making a new namespace in the global scope, something like:

```
window.APP = {
  someProp : someValue,
  ....
}
```

Are there any other options / good practices ?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916073/how-to-load-bootstrapped-models-in-backbone-js-while-using-amd-require-js/10288587#10288587

Comment: @shioyama Thanks for the link, but in my case this approach is a little overkill as i do not need to populate data from the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I always try to avoid global scoping when working with require.js, better is to avoid it.

A solution is to create a `config.js` file:

```
#config.js

define([], function() {
    return {
        someProp : someValue
    }
})
```

Then when you need to access those values in another module, you can do:

```
#foo-module.js

require(['config', 'backbone', 'underscore'], function(config, Backbone, _) {
    console.log(config.someProp)
})
```