# RequireJS undefined alias variable

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Because I need important settings from the serverside I am required to put the main file in the HTML file. But my problem now is that the alias files still load, but are not available as variable. (Also not in the app.js file or in other defined files.) So when I do this: (See bottom of the HTML page)

```
require([
  'jquery'
   'app'
], function($, App) {
   alert($);
   App.initialize();
});
```

The alert will show a undefined variable, but when I look at my loaded files. The jQuery file is loaded. (The same problem with the underscore and backbone variable, but not the app variable, it is a problem with only the aliases.)
Do you know how to solve this problem?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Domain.net</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="js/lib/modernizr.js"></script>

<script src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Require.js allows us to configure shortcut alias
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore',
        backbone: 'lib/backbone',
        templates: '../templates'
    }
});

define('config', function() {
    return {
        /** My serverside config */
    }
});

//Load the App
require([
    'jquery',
    'app'
], function($, App) {
    alert($);
    App.initialize();
});
</script>
```

Comment: what version of jquery are you using? if it's not recent then it won't work with amd. in that case, you'll need to add a shim that exports `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of jQuery you are using, but if it is not 1.7 or higher, then it will not support amd by default, which would explain why you get `undefined`. The best solution in that case would be to update it.

Alternatively, try adding a [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) with `exports: jQuery` to your config:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore',
        backbone: 'lib/backbone',
        templates: '../templates'
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: 'jQuery'
        }
    }
});
```

Also note that the way you are setting up your serverside config is prone to a race condition, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916073/how-to-load-bootstrapped-models-in-backbone-js-while-using-amd-require-js/13160285#13160285).

Comment: Currently I am using 1.8.2, but the problem is not only wiht jQuery but also Backbone and Underscore and all the other aliases. (Sorry for not mention that)

Comment: But thanks for the other answer. I will try that. Because I only use the config for one collection (Backbone)

Comment: Do you see any javascript errors (in the console)? If your paths are not working then you should see a `NetworkError: 404 Not Found` error.