# Having trouble defining global var in require.js

Tags: requirejs

I'm trying to define a global object that i can reference across all of my modules.  however, in the modules, i am unable to reference my path, and it's saying that "g" does not exist.

In main1.js, i have this:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    Underscore: 'lib/underscore/1.3.3/underscore.min',
    Backbone: 'lib/backbone/0.9.2/backbone.min',
    Globals: 'lib/backbone/ globalVars'
  }
});

require([ 'views/pages', 'views/filters'], function(allPages, filters) {
  filters.render();
  allPages.render();
});
```

inside globalVars.js, i have this:

```
(function() {
    var Globals = {
        isDemo: false
    }
    console.log('in globalvars') // this shows in my console
}).call(this);
```

and finally, inside of view/pages.js, i have this:

```
define([
  'Globals',
  'Underscore',
  'Backbone'
], function(g, _, Backbone){
console.log(g.isDemo)  //<-- returns "TypeError: g is undefined"
```

If i use a define inside my main1.js like this:

```
define( 'Globals', function() {
    return {
        isDemo: true
    }
})
```

it works just fine.  I haven't had much luck with trying to figure out why this is not working.  I'd like to be able to just include a path to the globalVars rather than boilerplate pasting a define block in each and every module that needs it, since changing isDemo to false would require updating many other module pages (main2.js, main3.js, etc) as well.   thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916073/how-to-load-bootstrapped-models-in-backbone-js-while-using-amd-require-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to start with, your `globalVars.js` is not in the module pattern, so requirejs doesn't know what you're trying to register as the module.  If you change that file to use  the pattern, like the define you added to main1.js, you should be all set.  Is there a reason you aren't defining it as a module?

Comment: thanks Waxen, that was it!  i am also using backbone and underscore, so i was under the impression that i had to define it in similar fashion.  I replaced the contents of Globals.js with the define block i pulled out out of main1.js, and now it's working!  good stuff!