# how to load backbone initial data to another js file

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js, external

here is my django rendered test page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="todo">
</div>
<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
<div>
  <input id="todo_complete" type="checkbox" <%= completed ? 'checked="checked"' : '' %>>
  <%- title %>
</div>
</script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="underscore.js"></script>
<script src="backbone.js"></script>

<script src="app.js"></script>
    //the app.js is my backbone app
<script >
    var foo_models = new fooCollection({{django_rendered_json_vaiable}})
    //this is how I get backbone collection initial data
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the above code is what I get so far, I get the backbone bootstrapped models as foo_models,
but **this variable can't be access in my app.js file**, then I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916073/how-to-load-bootstrapped-models-in-backbone-js-while-using-amd-require-js), which use AMD approach,but my app is fairly small,all I need is get the initial data in another js file,so I don't want to add require.js and I don't want to make this foo_models variable global。

so how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

*** EDITED ***

Just change these lines:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
    //the app.js is my backbone app
<script >
    var foo_models = new fooCollection({{django_rendered_json_vaiable}})
    //this is how I get backbone collection initial data
</script>
```

to:

```
<script >
    var raw_foo_models = {{django_rendered_json_vaiable}};
</script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Then, add this line:

```
var foo_models = new fooCollection(raw_foo_models);
```

somewhere in your app (after `fooCollection` has been defined).

Comment: that wont work, it will raise an error says "fooCollection" is undeined

Comment: Ah; I've revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: well fooCollection is define in app.js