# RequireJS pass config to module always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I've tried the solution in other SO post, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916073/how-to-load-bootstrapped-models-in-backbone-js-while-using-amd-require-js), but it didn't seem to work. I always got *undefined* as a result.

My configuration in my HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var require = {
        config: {
            'config': { --> if I change this to app, I could read the value in app.js
                userId: 1
            }
        }
    };
</script>
<script src="lib/require.min.js" data-main="app"></script>
```

My config module:

```
define(['module'], function (module)
{
    return {
        userId: module.config().userId,
        userName: "Test"
    }
});
```

I use the config module in my app.

```
require(['modules/config', 'modules/A'], function (config, a)
{
    var userId = config.userId; --> undefined
    var userName = config.userName; --> Test
});
```

Any idea? Did I miss something? I use JQuery 1.12.3 and RequireJS 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

Edit the config you pass to RequireJS to:

```
var require = {
  config: {
    'modules/config': {
      userId: 1
    }
  }
};
```

#### Explanation

Your modules ids are not matching. When you require your module, you use  `require(['modules/config', ...`. So the module name is `modules/config`. However, in your RequireJS configuration you provide a configuration for the module named `config`. So when you use `module.config()` inside `modules/config`, RequireJS searches for a module named `modules/config` in the configuration and does not find it. So you get undefined. Performing the fix I mentioned earlier will allow RequireJS to find the configuration.

Alternatively you could use `paths` to have the module be loaded under the name `config`:

```
var require = {
  paths: {
    config: 'modules/config'
  },
  config: {
    config: {
      userId: 1
    }
  }
};
```

And use `require(['config', ...`.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I'm new to RequireJS, trying to get the hang of it.

Comment: Glad to help. I'm not the one who downvoted your question, by the way. (Just saying, because the timing may make it look like I did.) I've actually upvoted because it is easy to get tripped by module ids in RequireJS.

Answer (score -1):

I followed the below technique to get it working. The files included in HTML. They can defined in `config` paths.

**Directory structure:**

```
-index.html
-modules
    - myModule.js
-app.js
```

**HTML** (index.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // require would refer to the require.js global. So i am using requireVar
    var requireVar = {
        config: {

                userId: 1

        }
    };
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.2.0/require.min.js"></script>
<script src="modules/myModule.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

file **myModule.js**

```
define("modules/myModule",function ()
{
    return function(){
        return requireVar.config.userId;
    }
});
```

and finally my **app.js**

```
require(['modules/myModule'], function (myModule)
{
    alert("");
    var userId = myModule(); 
    console.log(userId);
});
```